# Is it possible to remove resizing and closing of another application with C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, computer-science

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the ability to close OTHER windows using C#?

I know that you can override your windows' close() method, but is that also possible for other processes? And what about changing the window style of another process to fixed___ so it cannot be resized?

So far I have gotten the main window handle of the application and I have removed all buttons and menus, but I still need to figure out how to make it uncloseable and unresizeable.

Here's what I've got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThirdTest
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Constants
        //Finds a window by class name
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        //Sets a window to be a child window of another window
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        //Sets window attributes
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        //Gets window attributes
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool DrawMenuBar(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

        //assorted constants needed
        public static uint MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;
        public static uint MF_REMOVE = 0x1000;
        public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        public static int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000; //child window
        public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
        public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
        public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar 
        public static int WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000; //window menu
        #endregion

        public static void WindowsReStyle()
        {
            Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process proc in Procs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found process: " + proc.ProcessName.ToString());
                if (proc.ProcessName.StartsWith("notepad"))
                {
                    IntPtr pFoundWindow = proc.MainWindowHandle;
                    int style = GetWindowLong(pFoundWindow, GWL_STYLE);

                    //get menu
                    IntPtr HMENU = GetMenu(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    //get item count
                    int count = GetMenuItemCount(HMENU);
                    //loop & remove
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        RemoveMenu(HMENU, 0, (MF_BYPOSITION | MF_REMOVE));

                    //force a redraw
                    DrawMenuBar(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    SetWindowLong(pFoundWindow, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_SYSMENU));
                    SetWindowLong(pFoundWindow, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_CAPTION));

                }
            }
        }  

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WindowsReStyle();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? (:

As I've put in the comments, here are some more details on the issue:

I need two applications to be side-by-side on the monitor. 
None of them can be closeable or resizeable. One is a browser, the other is an application called "Z-tree". 
I have already fixed the issue with Z-tree as it, by default, runs with no closebutton and no resizing and you can specify the size and position of it in the command line.

Comment: Well, of course not.  Anybody can just kill the process with Task Manager and that window is going to be gone.  Taking excessive counter-measures when the alternative is so simple just isn't productive.

Comment: Are you talking about managed applications only, or *any*?

Comment: @HansPassant: It is for a onetime science project. Noone will be using the task manager - I just don't want them to be able to blatantly close it.

Comment: @WeylandYutani: A specific application (Internet Explorer or Google Chrome)

Comment: You could create a full-screen window with no close box that hosts a pair of [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) controls.

Comment: I need two applications to be side-by-side on the monitor. None of them can be closeable or resizeable. One is a browser, the other is an application called "Z-tree". I have already fixed the issue with Z-tree as it, by default, runs with no closebutton and no resizing and you can specify the size and position of it in the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another idea, create a winforms project and set the window so it cannot be resized. Then embed a single WebBrowser control in the form and navigate to your page in the form load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //catch form closing event to prevent form being closed using alt-f4
     FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;

     //remove close button from toolbar and remove window border to prevent
     //moving and resizing
     this.ControlBox = false;
     this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

     //set position to half of the screen
     this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2;
     this.Top = 0;
     this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2;
     this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

     //mark the window as a top level window, reducing users ability to alt-tab away
     TopMost = true;

     webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     //prevent form being closed
     e.Cancel = true;
}

//the only way to close the form
void DoExit()
{    
     //remove the closing handler first or it won't close
     FormClosing -= Form1_FormClosing;
     Close();
}
```

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea! Would I be able to make Form1 uncloseable, unresizeable and take up 50% of the screen?

Comment: yes setting ControlBox to false and formbordersize to fixedtoolwindow removes all the toolbar buttons and prevents resizing. Then you just need to initialize it with the right width and height

Comment: in fact setting FormBorderStyle to None is better as it removes the border completely and prevents the user moving the window

Comment: I have updated the code to prevent users being able to close the window with ALT-F4

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I havn't thought about this before!

Now all I have left to do is customize it so it looks as much as IE as possible (to not alienate the users).

Answer (score 0):

you can force internet explorer into an "unexitable" fullscreen mode if you start it with:

```
iexplore -k www.google.com
```

This is how shops and stuff get it to run so no-one can close it. Of course you can close it through task manager, but it just makes it difficult for most users to close it.

(CTRL-W will close it <--- secret key!)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780

Comment: This is not what I am looking for - I need two applications running side-by-side (both uncloseable).